# How do i import data to firebase that is in csv formate?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have date in form of csv and have to upload to firebase for an application is it possible to connect a csv file to firebase project?

Is it possible to do a bulk insert in firebase insted of manually entering the data?

Comment: I'd recommend against doing this manually, but it should be a fairly easy 2-step coding process: 1) read the CSV file, 2) write to Firestore using the API.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: @Ashish i havent tried yet iam very new at firebase nd firestore

Comment: Please post code where you read csv file rest i'll provide you.